# How to Pass an ArrayList to a Method in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I'm trying to pass a specific ArrayList as a parameter during runtime (I'm using BlueJ). But when I pass {5, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8} into my method, I'm getting an error: "illegal initialize for java.util.List".

Here is the gist of what my code is so far:

```
public static List<Integer> method(List<Integer> items)
    {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int first = items.get(0);
        list.add(first);
        return list;
     }
```

Comment: Please share the method call

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Green tick next to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call you're method by passing an instance of `List` (of a subclass of course), like this:

```
method(Arrays.asList(5, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8));
```

Or this newer [syntax in Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-E-) and later:

```
method(List.of(5, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8));
```

Your code `{ 5, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8 }` makes an array (see [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)) . But your method does not take an array. Your method declares that it takes an object of type [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html), a class from the [*Java Collections Framework*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework). The `ArrayList` class happens to use an array internally, but is *not* an array itself.

Comment: I'm calling this in my main method but when running the program I am not getting returned anything.

Comment: @BeanieLeung Did you try my code and using the result like `List<Integer> res = method(Arrays.asList(5, 2, 9, 1, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8));` then print res

Comment: ah, yes that works. thank you so much. Can you just explain why List<Integer> res needs to be included rather than just calling the method?

Comment: @BeanieLeung The method returns something, you need to use, save it in a variable or print it, what would you expect else ? You may read more tutos on coding, for all languages it'll be the same, the code won't things that you don't it to do ;)